# How does "Newly Installed Programs" work?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, hint

I'm building a program installer using NSIS. The executable file name is XYZ.exe and I want to install it in "$PROGRAM_FILES/XYZ 1.0/". I also create shortcuts in Menu Start: "$MENU_START/XYZ 1.0/XYZ 1.0" points to "$PROGRAM_FILES/XYZ 1.0/XYZ.exe"

After installing my software using the created installer the "newly installed software" hint is shown. Using the link does not make this hint to disappear. Here's a link to a short description how Windows treats newly installed programs. Unfortunately the information is not precise.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/24/496690.aspx

What do I have to do to make my link hide the hint? I do not want to disable those hints completely.

I also do not want to wait for it to disappear by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The highlight should go away after a while.

IMHO it is rather pointless to mess with this but if you really have to then you can try setting the [System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property on the shortcut. This is not really easy to do in NSIS though...

Comment: That's not really a solution... I just wonder if the .exe name has to be the same as the link name or what?

Comment: I mean: I wonder how windows triggers hiding the hint. Program runs from the shortcut but it does not make the hint go away. I do not want to hack the registry...

Comment: Your link says they go away after a week for sure. For me they go away pretty fast just by using the machine (launching the new program and other programs?)

Comment: Yup, it should go away automatically after one week. The thing is that **running my app does not turn this hint off**. So I want to know how Windows triggers this action. Do I have to match link name with .exe name or what?

Comment: It does not matter. It disappears only if I uninstall the program.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem and something you think you need to fix. It is by design and should go away just by using the machine...

Comment: It should go away when user runs the program. It does not - so there's an error somewhere. I don't want to wait utill it times out.

Comment: I don't know if there is any guarantee that it goes away just by running it a couple of times. The un-highlight algorithm is not known so we don't really know for sure. I still don't understand why you think it is a problem, clearly it is by design and the user can turn the feature off if they don't like it...

Comment: Look, just read the linked page. Here's the link again: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/24/496690.aspx?Redirected=true In short: if the feature system-wide is enabled then every new installed program is marked in menu. When you first run it this hint disappears. The hint will also disappear after one week from installing. In case of my program there's the hint but it does not vanish when I run the program using the link. I do not want to disable the feature, I just want it to work as it should.